# External Pull Up resistors connection to microcontroller output pins

Tags: lpc1768

Please let me know, can we connect External pull up resistor to output pin of a microcontroller

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: Some micros even have internal pullups/pulldowns that you can enable. Check the port block diagrams in the datasheet to see if you have this option.

Comment: Make sure not to exceed the sink/source ratings per IO pin and neither the (total) rating for the microcontroller itself.

Comment: Welcome to SE EE, please avoid using "Can we..." questions as a valid answer could be "yes" or "no". Also not everything that we **can** do is a good idea. Many modern microcontrollers have a build-in pull up (and/or pull down) resistor which can be switched on/off. So often external resistors aren't even needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Even if the MCU has built-in pullups that can be enabled there are valid reasons to use an external resistor. The internal pullups have a very loose tolerance and have a nominal value that was selected by the MCU maker to be generally useful - but not necessarily optimal for all situations (there may be some that have more than one possible value, but I've never run across one).

So if you want or need a very low value (perhaps for noise immunity or for I2C pullups that have to deal with capacitance) or a very high value (perhaps for low power consumption) or a tighter tolerance then an external pullup is an inexpensive way of getting that. Sometimes you want to put the pullup on the other side of a RC filter, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvFTZy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This can be used to allow suitable wetting current for the switch (R2), a low pass filter (could be used for debouncing if the MCU input is Schmitt trigger type). R3 limits the input current if the MCU Vcc is heavily and quickly pulled to ground and may not be necessary in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  An I2C output for example requires them.

https://os.mbed.com/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/

Other active outputs, a pullup is not really needed and can reduce the amount of low level output drive available to other devices.  If the outputs go into an undriven state during reset, than a pullup could be used to  hold outputs high until the program can take over to drive them high.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Most microcontrollers have the ability to switch some or all of the outputs into open drain mode, where the high side transistor of the usual push-pull output is disabled, allowing outputs to be connected in parallel, and share a single pull-up resistor, or for a single output to have a high logic level different to the supply of the microcontroller itself - many 3.3V supply microcontrollers will have some pins that will tolerate being pulled up to 5V in order to allow then to output to other chips running on a 5V supply.

[image from here](http://www.ermicro.com/blog/?p=1669)